# Unable to call jquery function when user clicks on Edit button in the second row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new to jquery, hence asking this dumb question.

Whenever I click on Add plan, a new row is getting created. but when I click on Edit button in the second row, that particular jquery fucntion(.editbtn) is not getting called, Please help me in this issue.

Here is my HTML Code.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ include file="../includes/taglib.jsp"%>



<security:authorize
access="hasAnyRole('SUPER_USER_EDIT', 'USER_EDIT', 'SUPER_USER_VIEW', 'USER_VIEW', 'INQUIRY_VIEW')">


<tiles:putAttribute name="title" cascade="false">Employer Details</tiles:putAttribute>
<tiles:putAttribute name="body_content" cascade="true">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="block-header">
                <h2>Employer Details</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body card-padding">
                    <table style="border-spacing: 50px; width: 50%;">
                        <tr>
                            <td><span class="input-group-addon  text-left p-5"><strong>Entity
                                No</strong></span> <span class="input-group-addon  text-left">1234567890</span>
                            </td>
                            <td><span class="input-group-addon  text-left p-5"><strong>Enterprise
                                Id</strong></span> <span class="input-group-addon  text-left">EM
                                12345678</span>
                            </td>
                            <td><span class="input-group-addon  text-left p-500"><strong>Name</strong></span>
                                <span class="input-group-addon  text-left">Accuride
                                Corporation</span>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="block-header">
                <h2>Employer Plan History</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body card-padding">
                    <input type="button" value="Add Plan" id="add_plan" onclick="addPlan('employerPlanHistory')"/>
                    <table id="employerPlanHistory" style="border-spacing: 50px; width: 100%;">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <TH id="planType"><FONT COLOR=grey FACE="Geneva, Arial" SIZE=3>Plan Type></FONT></TH>
                                <TH><FONT COLOR=grey FACE="Geneva, Arial" SIZE=3>Description></FONT></TH>
                                <TH><FONT COLOR=grey FACE="Geneva, Arial" SIZE=3>Version></FONT></TH>
                                <TH><FONT COLOR=grey FACE="Geneva, Arial" SIZE=3>Effective From></FONT></TH>
                                <TH><FONT COLOR=grey FACE="Geneva, Arial" SIZE=3>Effective To></FONT></TH>
                                <TH><FONT COLOR=grey FACE="Geneva, Arial" SIZE=3>Active></FONT></TH>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr id="tableRow" class="edit">
                                <td id="planType" contenteditable="false" style="min-width: 100px; max-width: 100px;">
                                    <select name="plantype">
                                        <option value="1">1</option>
                                        <option value="2">2</option>
                                        <option value="3">3</option>
                                        <option value="4">4</option>
                                        <option value="5">5</option>
                                        <option value="6">6</option>
                                        <option value="7">7</option>
                                        <option value="8">8</option>
                                    </select>
                                </td>
                                <td id="desc" contenteditable="false">Vitality</td>
                                <td id="version" contenteditable="false">1</td>
                                <td id="effDate" contenteditable="false">12/12/2015</td>
                                <td id="endDate" contenteditable="false">12/12/2019</td>
                                <td id="active" contenteditable="false">Yes</td>
                                <td>
                                    <button class="editbtn"/>
                                        Edit
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="block-header">
                <h2>Employer Contact History</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body card-padding">
                    <table style="border-spacing: 50px; width: 100%;">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <button type="button">Add Contract</button>
                                <button type="button">Save</button>
                                <button type="button">Cancel</button>
                                <br><br>
                                <TH><FONT COLOR=grey FACE="Geneva, Arial" SIZE=3>Contract No</FONT></TH>
                                <TH><FONT COLOR=grey FACE="Geneva, Arial" SIZE=3>Start Date</FONT></TH>
                                <TH><FONT COLOR=grey FACE="Geneva, Arial" SIZE=3>End Date</FONT></TH>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>1</td>
                                <td>12/12/2015</td>
                                <td>12/12/2019</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>
</tiles:putAttribute>
<tiles:insertDefinition name="DEFAULT_LAYOUT" />
```

```
$(document).ready(function () {
      var jqueryFunction=$('.editbtn').click(function () {
          alert("jquesy");
          var currentTD = $(this).parents('tr').find('td');
          if ($(this).html() == 'Edit') {                  
              $.each(currentTD, function () {
                  $(this).prop('contenteditable', true)
              });
          } else {
             $.each(currentTD, function () {
                  $(this).prop('contenteditable', false)
              });
          }

          $(this).html($(this).html() == 'Edit' ? 'Save' : 'Edit')

      });

  });

function addPlan(tableID){
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID).getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0]; 
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

    var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;
    for(var i=0;i<colCount;i++){
        var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
        newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;   
    } 

}

function onEdit(btn)
{
    var id=btn.id;
    if(btn.value=="Edit")
    {
    document.getElementById('planType'+id).removeAttribute("Readonly");
    document.getElementById('desc'+id).removeAttribute("Readonly");
    document.getElementById('version'+id).removeAttribute("Readonly");

    document.getElementById('effDate'+id).removeAttribute("Readonly");
    document.getElementById('endDate'+id).removeAttribute("Readonly");
    document.getElementById('active'+id).removeAttribute("Readonly");



    document.getElementById(id).value="Save";
    return false;
    }
    if(btn.value=="Save")
    {
    document.getElementById('planType'+id).setAttribute("Readonly" , "readonly");
    document.getElementById('desc'+id).setAttribute("Readonly" , "readonly");
    document.getElementById('version'+id).setAttribute("Readonly" , "readonly");
    document.getElementById('effDate'+id).setAttribute("Readonly" , "readonly");

    document.getElementById('endDate'+id).setAttribute("Readonly" , "readonly");

    document.getElementById('active'+id).setAttribute("Readonly" , "readonly");


    document.getElementById(id).value="Edit";
     return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: @rejithrkrishnan  , can you help me in this regard.

Comment: you should bind the event for dynamically created elements hence instead of `var jqueryFunction=$('.editbtn').click(function () {` use `var jqueryFunction=$('.editbtn').on('click',function () {` or `var jqueryFunction=$(document).on('click', '.editbtn',function () {`

Answer (score 1):

Use [**event delegation**](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) for binding events to dynamically added elements.

`$('.editbtn').click(functions(){})` will only bind the click event to `.editbtn` elements which is present in the DOM at the time of this code is excecuted. Which will not work for elements which are added after that.

In those scenarios you need to bind the events based on a parent element which will be there from the time the DOM is loaded.

Eg : `$(document).on('click', '.editbtn', function() {})`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('click', '.editbtn', function() {
        alert("jquery");
        var currentTD = $(this).closest('tr').find('td');
        if ($(this).html() == 'Edit') {
            $.each(currentTD, function() {
                $(this).prop('contenteditable', true)
            });
            $(this).html('Save');
        } else {
            $.each(currentTD, function() {
                $(this).prop('contenteditable', false)
            });
            $(this).html('Edit')
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: can you pls elaborate , in which part of the code , I need to make changes

Comment: @AdithyaVaraganti I added some details

Comment: you are awesome  rejith...Thank you, it is working fine now

Answer (score 0):

Event delegation allows us to attach a single event listener, to a parent element, that will fire for all descendants matching a selector, whether those descendants exist now or are added in the future. Meaning, whenever you create a new field, in the past what has been happening is there is no event listener on the EDIT button being created within the new row. Event delegation solves this problem, by adding an event listener to each of the dynamically created fields, so all of the fields that are created through your for loop within your addPlan function. @Rejithrkrishnan gave you the solution in his code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(document).on('click', '.editbtn', function() {
    alert("jquery");
    var currentTD = $(this).closest('tr').find('td'); //look closely here for his revision
    if ($(this).html() == 'Edit') {
        $.each(currentTD, function() {
            $(this).prop('contenteditable', true)
        });
        $(this).html('Save');
    } else {
        $.each(currentTD, function() {
            $(this).prop('contenteditable', false)
        });
        $(this).html('Edit')
    }
});
});
```